# I can't see my WAR file in webapps folder of Tomcat

Tags: maven, tomcat, web-applications, liferay, war

I can't see my WAR file in webapps folder of my Tomcat server directory.
My project is portal project and I am using Liferay portal technology hosted on Tomcat server. 
For deploying, I am using Maven configured goal name 'deploy'.
When I deploy the portlet module it generated the war file and I can see the file in deploy folder of my Liferay server but when I start the tomcat server it should ideally generate/move WAR file in 'webapps' folder of tomcat server directory but it is not doing that.
I have tried multiple options like deleting and re-configuring the server, setting Dynamic web-module version to 3.0 from 2.5 (as suggested in one of the post at StackOverflow) but nothing works for me.

I am stuck in this issue for long time and any help will be a great help..
Thanks

Comment: Which Liferay version are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you're using Liferay 7 or Liferay DXP. As these versions are built on OSGi, they're transforming the WAR files into an OSGi bundle (so called WAB, Web Application Bundle) and do not deploy them to tomcat, as you observe.

Prior versions did this, but not the current one.

As you don't state what else you'd expect: This is your answer - you're right, it's not there.

If you don't use Liferay 7 or DXP: Elaborate.